# "We care for our Nature" or "We care for Nature"?

Tags: grammar

Was drafting an email and my senior wanted to type "Planting saplings is our way of saying we care for our Nature".
I felt that's wrong English. Shouldn't it be "we care for Nature"? (it makes it a bit impersonal to remove the 'our', but if 'our nature' isn't right, can the cuteness factor of mentioning 'our nature' be preserved?. Which is correct?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right. Nature has (at least) two different meanings. When attributed to people, it tends to refer to their character/personality/beliefs/customs/heritage:

> It's not in his nature

means "he's not that kind of person, he wouldn't do that". So if we "care for our nature" we care for our character, traditions, behaviour - it's not about nature as in the natural environment. So I would change the phrase to one of these:

> We care for Nature
>
> We care for our natural environment
>
> We care for our environment
>
> We care for the environment

Comment: [Waggers’ answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/4796/waggers) is correct. I can only add that what in the question is referred to as *Nature* is very often referred to as *Mother Nature*. It's appropriate therefore to treat it as a proper noun and **not** use the definite article.

Answer (score 3):

In English *Our nature* would refer to [human nature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_nature), meaning the way humans are inherently inclined to behave.

Sometimes this sense can be extended to mean the way a particular individual is mentally wired. For example, the popular [frog and scorpion fable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Scorpion_and_the_Frog) ends with the scorpion killing them both by stinging the frog in mid-stream and explaining himself by saying, “It is my nature.”

On the other hand, when capitalized *Nature* is assumed to be talking about the natural world around us. It is a metaphorical concept that you can’t really put a possessive on, because it can’t be owned. Rather, it owns us.

If you really want to put a possessive on it, it should be changed to *our environment*.